# How to let browser send messages to a local java application?

Tags: java, php, browser

I want the browser to send a message to my local Java application (which is programmed by myself) when I click a button on a web page which is also written by myself using php. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: So, you want to create a Java web application, right?

Comment: My web page is written by php.

Comment: Then you may expose a web service from you java application and consume it from your PHP application.

Comment: In fact I intend to publish my web page on the server, then I can only visit it by the browser.But I still want the browser send a message to my java application by click on a button.Do I have to written a plugin on the browser?But it may be difficult to me.

Comment: No need for a browser plugin. Read Hendrik Brummermann's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way. You don't send information from your server to your local application. Your local application should grab the information from your web server.

Answer (score 0):

The local Java application can implement a webserver. There is a number of libraries out there, or you can use [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) / [SSLServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocket.html) to implement it low level. The server socket should be bound to localhost in order to prevent direct external access.

You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to communicate with this local webserver.

Pay special attention to authentication, because any website you visit, can instruct the browser to send requests to the local webserver.

Comment: Sorry, I think I haven't expressed my question correctly.In fact the web page is on the server.

Comment: And it is viewed by a browser, isn't it? The JavaScript is executed by the browser, not by the server. There is even a way without JavaScript: Tell the browser to load an image from localhost and encode the message into the local url: &lt;img src="http://localhost/command">